# Getting set-up for neural networks: external or internal GPU?

Tags: neural-network, gpu, external

I'm not sure I should be asking this here, but this seems like the one place I know of where people have a lot of practical experience with neural networks.

I'm trying to set up a rig for neural nets.  I've got a desktop tower, but I'd need to get a bigger power supply for the RTX 2080 GPU I'm considering and possibly more (noisy) fans.

But an option might be to attach an external GPU. An external solution addresses the above issues and  might make it possible to add GPUs if needed and perhaps makes the GPU mobile (use it at home and office).

Does anyone know what kind of performance hit an external GPU would involve? The RTX 2080 has a memory bandwidth of 448 GB/s compared with the T3's transfer rate of 5GB/s or, if it's possible to connect an external GPU directly to the PCI-e bus, maybe 32 GB/s. Then again, I don't know how much bandwidth is needed between the graphics card and the rest of the computer.  I'm also not sure whether linux works with external GPUs.

Anyone have any relevant info?

Comment: Memory bandwith is the same no matters the graphic card connection, it is the transfer rate between the GPU and its onboard memory.

Comment: Thanks Jules!  If I understand correctly, what matters is how fast the PCI-e bus is.  I said 32GB/s but the numbers seems to keep changing depending on what article I look at.  The one from yesterday pegged it at 16GB/s.  So, let's say that's the highest transfer rate for an *internal* card.  Question though is how much of that a deep neural network running on the card will actually use.  If it's 5GB or less, then an external card with a Thunderbolt 3 connector wouldn't lose much speed relative to an internal card (so I guess).  If it's above that, then we're looking at some loss.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the influence of TB3 bandwidth vs PCIe bandwidth for deep neural net, I just wanted to specify that memory bandwidth has nothing to do with external connection as it is only between onboard memory and gpu.